# How do I install an older version of the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

My app still has iOS12 users. However, I was informed that certain functions did not work on iOS 12. So I'm trying to debug, but I can't install the iOS 12 simulator. How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

To downgrade the simulator in Xcode, follow these steps:

1. Open Xcode.
2. Click on **Xcode** > **Preferences**.
3. In the **Preferences** window, select the **Downloads** tab.
4. In the **Downloads** tab, click on the **Add** button.
5. In the **Add Component** window, select the **Simulators** option.
6. In the **Simulators** window, select the version of the simulator you want to downgrade.
7. Click on the **Install** button.

Xcode will download and install the older version of the simulator.

Here are some additional things to keep in mind when downgrading the simulator:

- You can only downgrade the simulator to a version that is still supported by Apple.

Comment: These instructions do not seem to apply to Xcode 14. And even when the instructions are fixed, Xcode 14 does not support downloading any simulators earlier than iOS 13.7.